# Package doesn't relate on its internal node_modules packages dependencies, uses external scope instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs, yarnpkg

I can't figure out why project dependency `babel-polifyll` doesn't relate to its internal packages from the own `node_modules` root (they're present there actually). Instead, it trying to get some dependency packages from the same level as the common project `node_modules` scope...

I understand that this is not a bug in `babel-polifyll`, probably something happens in `node/yarn` environment for sure. Anyway, I can't spot what exactly wrong...

Error:[image]

Babel-polifyll `reqiure` imports that links from external scope:
[image]

Comment: What is your node/yarn version?

Comment: Why you don't use `@babel/polyfill`?

Comment: @VoKimNguyen node v10.15.3. yarn v1.17.3

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon it's not me, just a babel-polifyll instead use it under the hood.

Comment: From your project dir, could you run: `node -e "console.log(require.resolve.paths('code-js/shim'))" and check the path?
Anyway, I think there is some trouble in the yarn

Comment: can you please share your `package.json` this issue is related to conflicting versions of babel

Comment: Do you have ```package.json``` or ```package-lock.json```(or maybe you shouldn't share this lol) you can share? Try deleting package-lock.json if you have one, and run ```rm -rf node-modules && npm install --force```

Answer (score 1):

This is an NPM thing, it by default tries to install all packages at the root level, so dependencies can be shared between components. This way when you build your code, if you have three packages using same component, then you output file will only need to have one copy of the built sub-component in it. This keeps the file size down a lot.

NPM will put a dependancy as a child when two packages require different versions of a library and normally you would never notice when this happens, unless you go looking.

This is great when it works, which it does most of the time, but can be a bit of a pig to sort out when it goes wrong.

I just had a look and the latest version of core-js is v3.2.1, but babel-polyfil requires v2.6.5. So the quick fix might be to force install the older version.

```
npm i -D core-js@2.6.5
```

This might break something else, if that happens try doing

```
rm -rf node-modules package-lock.json
npm i
```

Hopefully that will the force what ever needs the newer version of core-is to install as a child dep and everything will then work for you.

Comment: Hey, @David! I'll try your solution. Will ping u once achieve something to discuss...